# start new activity after firebase authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, start-activity

this is my code.....
where to use intent in this code to start a new activity...
after the user email and password is registered the new activity should open.... i tried on my own but, it's starting new activity without registering. 
i want the user to go to secondactivity after registering.
    ` //defining view objects
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonSignup;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

```
//defining firebaseauth object
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

    //initializing firebase auth object
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //initializing views
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    //attaching listener to button
    buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void registerUser(){

    //getting email and password from edit texts
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //checking if email and passwords are empty
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    //if the email and password are not empty
    //displaying a progress dialog

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //creating a new user
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

   startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));

}

  @Override 

    public void onClick(View view) {

    //calling register method on click
    registerUser();
}
 }`
```

Comment: inside task.isSuccessful() if block.

Comment: you should put startActivity(new Intent()) inside the "if(task.isSuccessfull())" condition. Right now you are starting the new activity irrespective of the success or failure of your registration process.

Comment: TQSM... it worked

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- in your `task.isSuccessful` pass the `intent`

---

```
 firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                   startActivity(new Intent(current_activity.this,next_activity.class));
                }else{
                }

            }
        });
```

---

## Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

startActivity has to be called inside task.isSuccessful() method. Currently your are calling startActivity even before you get the success response.